# Use of .fileExporter

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i have added a fileExporter to my code so that when the user click the export button, it toggle the value of $showingExporter and expect to show the fileExporter. It works fine, except I found that it will call the method "CreateCSV" in my case no matter whether my button is clicked. The function CreateCSV will be called whenever my View dismiss. Any idea?

```
 var body: someView  {
       NavigationView {
          VStack {
              List {
                    Button(action: {self.showingExporter.toggle()}) {
                        Label("Export", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    }
              }
                
            }.fileExporter(isPresented: $showingExporter, document: createCSV(), contentType: .plainText) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let url):
                    print("Saved to \(url)")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }             
          }
       }
    }


private func createCSV() -> TextFile {
    print("CreateCSV")
 }
```

I found that whenever my view dismiss, it will call createCSV() once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftUI uses a declarative syntax so whenever your state changes iOS will redraw the views. In your case when the views redraw, your function createCSV will be called because its return value is an argument for the modifier fileExporter.
To fix this use a state variable for your document, pass it as an argument for fileExporter and toggle the value only when the document is ready.

Modify your code to

```
@State private var showingExporter: Bool = false

@State private var document: TextFile?

var body: some View  {
   NavigationView {
      VStack {
          List {
                Button(action: {
                    document = createCSV()
                    self.showingExporter.toggle()
                }) {
                    Label("Export", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                }
          }
        }
          .fileExporter(isPresented: $showingExporter, document: document, contentType: .plainText) { result in
          switch result {
            case .success(let url):
                print("Saved to \(url)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
       }
   }
}

private func createCSV() -> TextFile {
    print("CreateCSV")
    // Return your text file
    return TextFile()
}
```